# Relationship between assets/www files and src/*.java files in phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova

i was trying to understand the relationship between the `js` (functions or actions) files in `assets/www` and java files in `src` folder, it's clear that in `MainActivity` we load `index.html` in the `WebView` ! i was trying to understand this relationship but i still have the same problem and i can not implemente this [example](https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications/tree/master/Android) !?

Comment: your question is nor clear enough, but if i understand , the MainActivity role is just to load the file index.html from assets/ in the WebView, and then , all the work and transitions in the app are managed by Javascript and methods from the cross plateform ( phonegap). unless you are not using Plugins or JavaInterfaces for your WebView to execute native code in your WebView or the opposite

Comment: i trying to implement push notification plugin if u check the example in the question, the thing that i can't understand that what is relation between PushNotifications.js and   the GCM java class in src folder

Comment: as i told you, Plugins in cordova are interfaces between the native code and the javascript code , check this guide for more details about Plugins : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: Ok thanks Mr Houcine for the reply and help (^_^)

Comment: your welcome,, i will put this as answer and accept it , And  just take a look in the guide from the comment below and you will understand why and how to use Plugins ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is nor clear enough, but if i understand , the `MainActivity` role is just to load the file `index.html` from `assets/` in the `WebView`, and then , all the work and transitions in the app are managed by `Javascript` and methods from the cross plateform ( *phonegap*). Unless you are not using `Plugins` or `JavaInterfaces` for your `WebView` to execute native code in your `WebView` or the opposite

`Plugins` in cordova are interfaces between the native code and the javascript code , check this [guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) for more details